# How to format the console output received from a function? I want to add a newline after every '<' character

Tags: python

`print(video.streams.filter(only_audio=True))` prints

```
[<Stream: itag="139" mime_type="audio/mp4" abr="48kbps" acodec="mp4a.40.5" progressive="False" type="audio">, <Stream: itag="140" mime_type="audio/mp4" abr="128kbps" acodec="mp4a.40.2" progressive="False" type="audio">, <Stream: itag="249" mime_type="audio/webm" abr="50kbps" acodec="opus" progressive="False" type="audio">, <Stream: itag="250" mime_type="audio/webm" abr="70kbps" acodec="opus" progressive="False" type="audio">, <Stream: itag="251" mime_type="audio/webm" abr="160kbps" acodec="opus" progressive="False" type="audio">]
```

Now I want to insert a new line every time '<' is encountered but I'm not sure how I should go about doing this.

Here's my code:

```
from pytube import YouTube

video = YouTube('https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=d6uN9xYUMxE')
print(video.streams.filter(only_audio=True))

#I tried the following but it did not work.
for i in video.streams #invalid syntax
    print(i)
```

Comment: @JohnnyMopp `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 4, in <module>
    print(video.streams.filter(only_audio=True).replace("<", "<\n"))
AttributeError: 'StreamQuery' object has no attribute 'replace'`

Comment: @JohnnyMopp You have to cast it as string `str()`  like that: `print(str(video.streams.filter(only_audio=True)).replace("<", "<\n"))`

Comment: @Cardstdani Yes, it was not clear from the question what that function returned.

Comment: @dumpieceofshit did it solve the problem?

Comment: @Cardstdani  Yes. Apparently I was missing a semicolon. Casting it to string did the trick. And combined with the replace function, it did exactly what I wanted it to. Thanks a lot man

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot to add the `:` at the end of the for loop:

```
for i in video.streams #invalid syntax
    print(i) 

for i in video.streams: #correct syntax
    print(i)
```

Comment: Oh I feel stupid now. yeah that was the issue. Sorry I am more familiar with C.

Comment: @user17007422 You will get used to it with practice and time. Also, don't forget to leave your feedback by voting and accepting if it was useful, in order to improve this community.